# Join Sales table with Sales Region table based on Sales person and the date of the sale

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of sales, but it does not include the region of the sale. I also have a table of the assignment of our sales people based on the region and dates they were assigned. I want to join the tables so I can grab the region and include it into my sales table.

I join on the sales person's initial (key), but I also want to compare the date of the sale to the region start and region stop to join the correct region. I tried using the sale date BETWEEN the start and stop, but that did not work because if they are still currently in the region, it provides a NULL value.

Thanks for any help, Brent

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    select * from sysobjects where name='sales' and xtype='U'
)CREATE TABLE sales (
    [Sale_Date] DATETIME,
    [Sales_Person] NVARCHAR(3),
    [Sales_Amount] INT,
    [Region] INT
);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES
    ('2016-07-01 00:00:00',N'MDD',152,NULL),
    ('2016-09-21 00:00:00',N'MDD',278,NULL),
    ('2018-03-01 00:00:00',N'STE',385,NULL),
    ('2018-04-01 00:00:00',N'MDD',426,NULL),
    ('2019-02-25 00:00:00',N'MDD',224,NULL),
    ('2020-02-15 00:00:00',N'STE',261,NULL),
    ('2020-03-01 00:00:00',N'STE',480,NULL),
    ('2020-06-05 00:00:00',N'BBB',245,NULL),
    ('2020-07-05 00:00:00',N'BBB',178,NULL);


IF NOT EXISTS (
    select * from sysobjects where name='SalesPersonAssignment' and xtype='U'
) CREATE TABLE SalesPersonAssignment (
    [sales_person] NVARCHAR(4),
    [Region_ID] INT,
    [Region_Name] NVARCHAR(6),
    [Region_Start_Date] DATETIME,
    [Region_Stop_Date] NVARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO SalesPersonAssignment VALUES
    (N'MDD',2,N'North ','2015-01-05 00:00:00',N'12/31/2017'),
    (N'MDD',6,N'West','2018-01-01 00:00:00',N'NULL'),
    (N'STE ',6,N'West','2018-10-02 00:00:00',N'12/31/2019'),
    (N'STE',2,N'North ','2020-01-01 00:00:00',N'NULL'),
    (N'BBB',1,N'South','2019-01-01 00:00:00',N'NULL');



Select s.Sale_Date, s.Sales_Amount, s.Sales_Person, spa.Region_Name
FROM sales s LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesPersonAssignment spa ON s.Sales_Person = spa.sales_person
--join based on the sales date and region's start/stop date of the sales person
```

Comment: Side note - I think it would be better to make SalesPersonAssignment.Region_Stop_Date a nullable datetime type instead of nvarchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing a date as a string. And the time component is unnecessary.  The better approach is:

```
CREATE TABLE SalesPersonAssignment (
    [sales_person] NVARCHAR(4),
    [Region_ID] INT,
    [Region_Name] NVARCHAR(6),
    [Region_Start_Date] DATE,
    [Region_Stop_Date] DATE
);
```

```
INSERT INTO SalesPersonAssignment VALUES
    (N'MDD',2,N'North ','2015-01-05','2017-12-31'),
    (N'MDD',6,N'West','2018-01-01', NULL),
    (N'STE ',6,N'West','2018-10-02', '2019-12-31'),
    (N'STE',2,N'North ','2020-01-01', NULL),
    (N'BBB',1,N'South','2019-01-01', NULL);
```

Just include those conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT s.Sale_Date, s.Sales_Amount, s.Sales_Person, spa.Region_Name
FROM sales s LEFT OUTER JOIN
     SalesPersonAssignment spa
     ON s.Sales_Person = spa.sales_person AND
        s.Sale_Date >= spa.Region_Start_Date AND
        (s.Sale_Date <= spa.Region_End_Date OR spa.Region_End_Date IS NULL);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgetting the ON was just a typo. That is the first thing I tried, but the null value in the sps.region_end_date is null causes the returned results to be null. Thanks

Comment: @Brent . . . It wouldn't occur to me that one date would be stored as a string.  Fix the data model!

Comment: it works perfectly. The last part of the ON statement was tripping me up. Thank you for the help and I will do a better job of posting questions in the future.